# SharePoint Reminders

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, reminder

How would one setup a reminder based on a column in SharePoint? Let's say I have the below:

Document Owner - Name
Next Scheduled Review - 10/15/2017

As columns in SharePoint and I want to set a reminder that 5 days before the Next Scheduled Review send a reminder to the document owner. Anybody have any quick suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your reminder via SharePoint designer workflow as the following

[image]

You can get `Find Interval Between Dates` Action below `Utility actions` in `SharePoint 2010 /2013 platform` to get the date diff (5 days) between your `Next Scheduled Review` and `current date` so if the difference is 5 days it should send a mail to document owner column.